# The antiforgery token could not be decrypted

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I have an identity server asp net core project deployed in Azure, i also have two asp net 5 mvc client using my identity server as SSO, and continuously i am getting(save in logs) an exception

> The antiforgery token could not be decrypted.

Comment: I registered the anti forgery token by default with `services.AddMvc()`, and check all my views and i have only a `<form>` tag each view.

Comment: Can you please provide code snippets?

Comment: In my startup.. ```services.AddMvc(o => 
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                     .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                     .Build();
                o.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            });```

Answer (score 8):

We had similar issue today. We were able to resolve by persisting data protection keys to file system.

```
services.AddDataProtection()
        .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(@"\\UNC-PATH"));
```

Comment: I am using Identity Server 4 (asp.net core web api + Angular6 solution), each time after a new publish for Identity Server4 web application, there would be some end users facing cannot login issues as following error log:  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.AntiforgeryValidationException: The antiforgery token could not be decrypted.

Comment: ---> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The key {174446f3-3c8c-4bc8-8c99-e39901c320b3} was not found in the key ring.

Comment: at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.UnprotectCore(Byte[] protectedData, Boolean allowOperationsOnRevokedKeys, UnprotectStatus& status)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.DangerousUnprotect(Byte[] protectedData, Boolean ignoreRevocationErrors, Boolean& requiresMigration, Boolean& wasRevoked)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.Unprotect(Byte[] protectedData)

Comment: at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.Internal.DefaultAntiforgeryTokenSerializer.Deserialize(String serializedToken)

Comment: we applied Yousuf's solution to keep the data protection keys.

Comment: But one not good thing is, we need to manually maintain the expired data protection keys otherwise the folder size will be keep growing.

Comment: Note: This solution could only working on one IIS node. If your application is running under load balance setup, it will not work.

Comment: @Yousuf What is UNC-PATH ?

Comment: @ChinaHelloWorld Do you know how we can manage it in load balancer setup. As I am facing this issue with load balancer setup and IDS4

Answer (score 0):

We had the same error message

> Antiforgery token validation failed. The antiforgery token could not
> be decrypted.

on an app which runs on disributed instances, we decreased the instance to one then problem is solved. This solution may save hours of someone one day.